# assignment operator not working

Tags: c++, operators

What does this code:

```
MyClass t;
t = MyClass(100);
```

I have used something like that in my code and I get compilation error `error: no match for ‘operator=’`. Me I interpret it like in Java but apparently it's different.

I have the assignment operator declared like this:

```
MyClass& operator=(Myclass& other)
```

When I change my code to this it works:

```
MyClass temp(100);
t = temp;
```

I can't do this:

```
Myclass t(100)
```

Comment: "it works" Meaning? "I can't do this" Why not?

Comment: You have `Myclass` and `MyClass` mixed throughout there.  Please copy your actual code.

Comment: t is member of my class and I initialize in constructor. If I do that I got compile error

Comment: C++ memory management is totally different from Java's. When you declare `MyClass t;` you have a completely default constructed instance of `MyClass` on the stack. Why can't you do `MyClass t(100);`? That's no different than doing `MyClass temp(100);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the rhs declared as a const referece

```
MyClass& operator=(const Myclass& other);
```

When you have

```
t = MyClass(100);
```

The right hand side is a temporary, and a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary object.

You latter attempt

```
MyClass t2(100);
t = t2;
```

creates a named object `t2`, since this is an actual non-const lvalue, your assignment operator's parameter is able to bind to it.

You can see this directly if you were to try

```
MyClass& r1 = MyClass(100); // invalid, non-const ref to temporary
const MyClass& r2 = MyClass(100); // valid, const ref to temporary
MyClass mc(100);
MyClass& r3 = mc; // valid, non-const ref can bind to a named object
                  // as long as the object itself isn't declared const
const MyClass& r4 = mc; // valid, you can bind a non-const ref as well
```

Comment: Do I need also to create an operator for non-const value if do this?

Comment: @user230137, No, you're just saying you won't change the argument. This is opposed to your original definition, where you require that the argument is something you can change, despite not changing it.

Comment: @user230137 no, a const reference says you aren't going to change the object you are referencing, that's also fine to do with a non-const.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment operator should take a const reference as parameter. Because the temporary MyClass(100) cannot be bound to a non-const reference, your current implementation cannot be called.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the assignment

```
t = MyClass(100);
```

the object on the right side of the assignment is a *temporary* object, and you can't have references to temporary objects. You can however have a *constant* reference, so if you define the assignment operator like

```
MyClass& operator=(const Myclass& other)
```

it will work.

And it will also work if you use the new C++11 rvalue-reference:

```
MyClass& operator=(Myclass&& other)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot const 
C++ compiler should bind const object in the Right side

MyClass& operator=(const Myclass& other);